# How can i normilize my image to follow mpeg7 i don't know how to move the eyes tho the right coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I'm a novice in python and I'm trying to normalize an image in accordance with mpeg7 for a face detection algorithm however I'm having issues with changing the eyes coordinates to the specified ones so my question is how can I move the eyes coordinates on a matrix for example right eye [50, 70] and left eye [65, 72] and I want to turn there coordinates into the right eye [15, 24] left eye[32, 24].

correctly I've done the face and eyes detection through haar cascade, I've performed face rotation and I've scaled it already. however, mpeg7 dictates that the image should be normalized the dimension 46 by 56 monochrome with 255 levels and eyes align horizontally at line 24 and columns 16 and 32 respectively. for the code, I've followed this link https://datahacker.rs/010-how-to-align-faces-with-opencv-in-python/

Comment: this is a verbatim repost of [the previous one you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984155/how-can-i-move-the-eye-coordenates-in-an-matrix). you haven't addressed the requests for clarification you've been given on the previous question.

Comment: Sorry i don't know of a way to give more detail than this i gave further detail in the old question but since is closed i figured i should also create a new question with the new info added and the link with code i used however i can say tha main main issue is how to move the eyes to the coordinates i specifid without move the rest of the image is there a method tha switches the coodinates of points in a  matrix or i will have to calc a vector and translate the specific point

Comment: also if is there a easier faster way of comunicate my ideia with someno i'm open to it

Comment: ah, you edited the previous question recently, so there is some more description. I did not notice that.

Comment: yes, sorry probably was't the right way to do it